# Case sensitive formula in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells

I’ve been playing with this formula because I couldn’t get the original syntax to work and it’s nearly doing what I would like. Please can you help me make it case insensitive?

Here is the data and my current formula:
[image: formula]

[image: cells]

Comment: The SEARCH function is case-insensitive, so what is the problem?

Comment: You can make anything case-insensitive by using UPPER() on all alphanumerics; that way you're always comparing upper-case characters. see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UPPER-function-C11F29B3-D1A3-4537-8DF6-04D0049963D6

Comment: Create auxiliary column and use the formula in B2:B11 **=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)**, in C2 enter formula: **=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:B11=1,A2:A11,""))**

Comment: @lmi,, you are already using `SEARCH`,  is `case-insensitive` and it allows using the `Wildcard characters` also,, then could you plz write us what's problem you are facing??